# OracleDataAdapter.Update Обновление страницы

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение под пустой проект ASP.NET. В качестве бд использую Oracle 11g xe. Добавил на страницу грид. И без всяких мастеров записываю в него таблицу вот так вот:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from personel", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Personel");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Потом сделал добавление записи в эту таблицу вот таким вот образом:

```
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into personel (surname, name, patronymic) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')", con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

И начал делать обновление страницы что бы она автоматически обновлялась после изменения данных в таблице. Нашёл код на msdn и вроде бы всё работает. Но вот в чём проблема. Я вынес код апдейта в отдельную функцию, и юзаю её в баттоне вместе с кодом добавления записи. Выглядит это вот так:

```
            public DataSet PageUpdate()
        {
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("select * from personel", con);
            OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.Update(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into personel (surname, name, patronymic) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')", con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            PageUpdate();
        }
```

Но проблема в том что если это будет так выглядеть то апдейт будет отставать на 1 запись. То есть я добавлю 2 записи а обновит он только первую из них. То есть просто не обновляет последнюю запись. Но есть вынести код апдейта в отдельную кнопку. То всё будет работать правильно. То есть я нажал на первую кнопку, запись добавилась. Я нажал на вторую, страница обновилась. Но мне нужно что бы это работало в одной кнопке. Подскажите пожалуйста что у меня с кодом не так. Не как не могу понять. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, используйте параметризованные SQL запросы.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Ваш код в `PageUpdate` ничего (полезного) не делает. Вот как надо:

```
private void FillGridData()
{
  DataSet ds = GetGridDataSet();
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}

// instead of PageUpdate
private DataSet GetGridDataSet()
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  con.Open();
  OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from personel", con);
  da.Fill(ds, "Personel");
  con.Close();

  return ds;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillGridData();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.Open();
  OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into personel (surname, name, patronymic) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')", con);
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();

  FillGridData();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно за помощь, но ваш вариант работает так же как и мой. То есть оставляет последнюю запись не обновлённой. И почему в этом варианте не используется `da.Update();` по сути то что вы предложили это перезапись datasource. Это корректно? но в любом случае нужен рабочий вариант.

Comment: @Андрей Вы неправильно скопировали мой код к себе в проект.

Comment: А нет извиняюсь, я функцию в баттоне перепутал. Всё работает. Но всё же почему вы предложили тупо переписать datasource вместо использования специально для этого существующего OracleDataAdapter.Update. Разве с ним нельзя так сделать?

Comment: @Андрей - "тупо" - Вы не в компании шпаны, курящей за школой. Метод `OracleDataAdapter.Update` предназначен для перенесения изменений из датасета (находящегося в памяти) в базу данных, а не для обновления данных в контроле (как Вы, очевидно, думаете). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at8a576f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ну в таком случае я не понимаю для чего он нужен. У меня например в бд переносится всё и без него.

Comment: @Андрей Не страшно, попробую объяснить. Очень часто, с данными таблицы (имеется в виду таблица базы, не контрол) удобно работать в памяти, делая изменения многих полей и записей без постоянных обращений к базе данных (что является довольно дорогой по времени операцией). Для удобства работы с данными в памяти имеются такие классы как `DataSet` и `DataTable`. Когда эти изменения готовы для сохранения в базу, используется `OracleDataAdapter.Update`, который анализирует все изменения, делит их на insert/update/delete операции и все эти операции выполняет.

Comment: @Андрей Вы вставляете запись сразу в базу данных. Вам или надо сделать то, что показано в ответе, или вставить такую же запись (`DataRow`) в таблицу датасета, прикрепленного к `GridView1` и вызвать `GridView1.DataBind();`. Или вообще развернуть логику, и вставлять запись только в таблицу датасета, вызывать `Update` адаптера и `DataBind()` грида.